# How to copy WPF grid cell to another cell in the same grid

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, grid, copy

I have a grid 17x13, with each cell containing an image and another grid 2x2 and each of those cells contains a image.
The xaml for this is: (the Grid_0_0 repeats a LOT so this is just the main jist of it)

```
<Canvas x:Name="baseContainer">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=baseContainer, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=baseContainer, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
        <Grid x:Name="Grid_0_0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="Baseimg_0_0" Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "0" Source = "/psyduck larger.jpg" Stretch = "Fill" Visibility="Visible" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
            <Image x:Name="Altimg_0_0_TL" Source="/psyduck larger.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="Hidden" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Baseimg_0_0, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Baseimg_0_0, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Image x:Name="Altimg_0_0_TR" Source="/psyduck larger.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="Hidden" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Baseimg_0_0, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Baseimg_0_0, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <Image x:Name="Altimg_0_0_BL" Source="/psyduck larger.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="Hidden" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Baseimg_0_0, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Baseimg_0_0, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            <Image x:Name="Altimg_0_0_BR" Source="/psyduck larger.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="Hidden" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Baseimg_0_0, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Baseimg_0_0, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
```

These 'minigrids' slide one grid cell up, down, left, or right depending on which arrow key is pressed. Each cell would then be visually in the location of a neighboring cell.
Finally I would copy the contents of the moved cell to the cell that it has moved on top of.

I tried to do it simply with

```
Grid_0_0 = Grid_0_1;
```

But it didn't result in any change actually made. Or at least it didn't copy the values such as "visible" and "hidden".
and I also tried doing a foreach loop for it.

```
private void ResetBoardSlide()
    {
        foreach (Grid grid in MainGrid.Children) 
        { 
            grid.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);
            grid = Grid_0_0;
        } 
    }
```

But this one didn't work because of "CS1656 C# Cannot assign to because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'" Which looking into it, seems to be because foreach is a read only thing. neat. But is there any built in, or simple way, to copy all children and their state to another cell?

Comment: Another way of doing this would be to use a wrappanel. You could make that the itemspresenter of an itemscontrol and bind a collection of picture viewmodels. The order in the collection would drive position left to right and then next row.... and so on. Your could load the same viewmodels into a 2d array so indexing is easier to work with. Rather then move viewmodels, change properties in them. Or a child object within each.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't messed with wrappanel, but I did try some with UniformGrid. I also have an array of the minigrids 'Grid[,] board = new Grid[13,17];' but i'm not entirely sure if those are references or what... I fill it in another method. The main struggle i'm having is how to change the properties or a child object within them I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to programmatically change the value of the attached properties (Grid.RowProperty, and Grid.ColumnProperty) of your minigrids "Grid_0_0" object. Suppose you have a callback of your key press event, the code should be look like this

```cs
private void OnKeyPress(KeyNameEnum key)
{
    switch(key)
    {
        case KeyNameEnum.Up: 
             Grid_0_0.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, ((int)Grid_0_0.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty))-1);
             break;
        case KeyNameEnum.Down:
             Grid_0_0.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, ((int)Grid_0_0.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty))+1);
             break;
        case KeyNameEnum.Left: 
             Grid_0_0.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, ((int)Grid_0_0.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty))-1);
             break;
        case KeyNameEnum.Right:
             Grid_0_0.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, ((int)Grid_0_0.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty))+1);
             break;
        default:
             break;
    }
}
```

Of couse, you need add the boundary check to prevent the minigrids literally going off the grids.

Comment: Ah so by changing the RowProperty and ColumnProperty, it's sorta like changing a pointer to the minigrid object so the main grid will point to the neighbor? 
Could you clarify what the SetValue function you show is doing? I believe the first value is what is being changed, and the second is the new value, but why typecast to int and what is xButton?

Comment: I'm using ```System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue``` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject.setvalue?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1})  The reason we need to type cast here, is that DependencyObject.GetValue returns an object, compiler will give an error unless we type-cast to int before perform "+" operattion.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. xButton should be Grid_0_0. I've updated my answer here.

Comment: FYI Tommy. Grid.Row and Grid.Column are attached properties. They "attach" to any old bit of UI. A grid looks for these properties when it's laying out it's children. So the properties have meaning to the grid but not the children.

Comment: I am confused by Grid.Row and Grid.Column... I am using Visual Studio and when I try to use these I get an error _CS1061 C# 'Grid' does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no accessible extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of type 'Grid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_ This doesn't seem to be the first time someone references a method/property that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I believe you've figured out to use "Grid.RowProperty" instead of "Grid.Row" in the code behind

Comment: Ah so I have. In my testing it seems that this method is _moving_ the minigrids to another cell. How would one go about copying the preexisting children elements from one main grid cell to another so that a cell isn't left empty after the contents are moved?

Comment: You need to dynamically create a minigrid , and add that minigrid to MainGrid as child item.